# GEOMfromEWKB missing

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am quite new to `psql` and I am trying to carry on a work that has been started by someone else.

I am trying to import an sql dump he made, and I am having the following errors:

> psql:nameofdatabase.sql:3847: ERROR:  could not find function
>   "LWGEOMFromWKB" in file "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/lib/postgis-2.2.so"
>   psql:nameofdatabase.sql:3850: ERROR:  function
>   postgis.geomfromewkb(bytea) does not exist

It seems to me from the `\df` command that the `geomfromewkb()` function is here but is in the `public` schema. This should not be a problem then for psql to find it right, since when I do

```
SHOW search_path;

public,$user,data,tiger
```

are here.

Does anyone know about this and can tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: The problem is not in PostgreSQL but in the shared library `postgis-2.2.so` which does not have the `LWGEOMFromWKB()` function that the PostgreSQL function refers to. Are the PostGIS versions between the two systems the same? Probably better ask this in the PostGIS forums.

Comment: @Patrick Thanks. Indeed I think the dump was done using postgis-2.1. I tried to install that but it seem incompatible with the version of `psql` I had. But what seems strange to me is that this function seems to be here in the public schema. I will try to post in a PostGIS forums and see if anyone else had this problem. From PostGIS website, they don't seem to mention any change w.r.t to this function, in the change log.